# Docker 1.7 consuming more space than Docker 1.5 for images

Tags: ubuntu, docker, vagrant, dockerfile

Initially i had docker 1.5 installed  in `ubuntu Trusty` via Vagrant.

Then i created new `Ubuntu Trusty` and now the docker version is `1.7`.

I tried building Image of my Postgres Container with this Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty

RUN echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main universe" > /etc/apt/sources.list

RUN apt-get -y update

RUN apt-get -y install wget openssh-server

RUN apt-get install -y supervisor

RUN mkdir -p /var/run/sshd

RUN wget --quiet --no-check-certificate -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | apt-key add -

RUN echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ trusty-pgdg main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list

RUN apt-get -y update

RUN apt-get -y upgrade

RUN locale-gen --no-purge en_US.UTF-8

ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8

RUN update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8

RUN apt-get -y install postgresql-9.3 postgresql-contrib-9.3 postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1 postgis

RUN echo "host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5" >> /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf

RUN service postgresql start && /bin/su postgres -c "createuser -d -s -r -l docker" && /bin/su postgres -c "psql postgres -c \"ALTER USER docker WITH PASSWORD 'docker'\"" && service postgresql stop

RUN echo "listen_addresses = '*'" >> /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf

RUN echo "port = 5432" >> /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf

EXPOSE 5432 22

ADD start.sh /start.sh

RUN chmod 0755 /start.sh

cmd ["supervisord", "-n"]
```

Now when i check my ubuntu with docker 1.5 the

```
Filesystem           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1             40G  2.3G   36G   6% /
none                 4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
```

When i check on docker 1.7 then

```
Filesystem           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1             40G   14G   24G  38% /
none                 4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
```

I have specifically tested with only one image and nothing else on the server.

I have even checked the disk usage and its coming from `/var/lib/docker/vfs/dir`

I want to know what have changed in 1.7 thats causing this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a known issue

extract from 
https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-1-7-0-is-using-huge-amount-of-disk-space/2046/2

"Reason seems to be missing aufs settings on install script https://get.docker.com/ubuntu/"

the fix is

"Works fine when installed docker with https://get.docker.com script."